# Pressure Cooker suitable for traditional Indian dishes, available in Europe

Tags: indian-cuisine, pressure-cooker

I would like to try recipes from [Urvashi Pitre](https://twosleevers.com/faces-behind-food-urvashi-pitre/)'s [*Indian Instant Pot Cookbook: Traditional Indian Dishes Made Easy and Fast*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1939754542). However, buying the original [Instant Pot](https://instantpot.com/) pressure cooker does not seem to be straightforward or convenient for customers in Europe (outside Britain).

Has anybody tried these recipes with a pressure cooker that is more readily available in Europe (Germany)? I'm still used to old-fashioned models without any electronic controls, so I am wondering what could be a good alternative option to acquire.

**UPDATE** Here is a [sample recipe](https://twosleevers.com/now-later-butter-chicken-pressure-cooker/) from the book (linked from [this](https://www.newyorker.com/culture/annals-of-gastronomy/the-butter-chicken-lady-who-made-indian-cooks-love-the-instant-pot) article in *The New Yorker*).

Comment: Do you already have the book? A sample recipe might help us work out the difference between cooking using the instant pot and using a normal pressure cooker. It shouldn't be hard to adapt. Failing that, I'm sure there are other, more generic, Indian recipe books for pressure cookers.

Comment: @ChrisH I've added a link to a sample recipe.

Comment: Look for products described as programmable pressure cooker

Comment: I think amazon UK has a selection of Hawkins cookers?

Comment: I'm not an expert in pressure cooking, not by a long way, but there's nothing special about that recipe that couldn't be adapted by someone who is.

Comment: @ChrisH This OP also is not such an expert.

Comment: No, but with the information you've added, the question is now answerable by one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything "special" about that recipe that depends on the particular pressure cooker. I don't think you need anything fancier than an old-fashioned pressure cooker and a timer, assuming you know how to use an old-fashioned pressure cooker. If you already own one, why buy another?

Figure time on "high" to be time on 15 PSI (or 1 bar) steam, and cook away.

A brief glance at the link shows a thing that seeks to be everything (pressure cooker, rice cooker, yogurt maker, really should have [Ron Popeil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Popeil) do ads for it on late night TV...) some of which would be more difficult in a regular pressure cooker, though (for instance) we had a spot on the stove over a pilot light that could make any pot into a yogurt-maker if you set it there full of milk and culture. And you can certainly make rice in a pressure cooker under pressure, rather than trying to mimic a "rice cooker" at atmospheric pressure.

Comment: +1 I do not yet own a pressure cooker but know how to use old-fashioned models from way back. I will probably acquire such a model, because I don't like (am not yet used to) the idea of a pot that sits on the stove *and* requires a power cable. A [WMF Perfect Pro](https://www.wmf.com/en/pots-pans/pressure-cookers-1/single-pots/pressure-cooker-3-0l-perfect-pro-0796219990.html) may be a good quality choice.

Comment: The specialty about indian pressure cooked recipes is that they measure time by whistles not by wall time .....

Comment: @Drux, _pot that sits on the stove and requires a power cable_ I think most people place it on their counter.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Thx for that clarification.